# Visual Studio compiler errors (can't use commas)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having a problem with my Visual Studio with C#. I'm creating console applications using .NET 5.0 (current).

Whenever I compile my program and put in decimal numbers (example: 62.5 it saves it as 625). How do I fix this?

Here's the code I've been using (it also does not save the commas on every other program). This program chooses the biggest number of the 3 inputs

```cs
using System;

namespace OEFGREATEST
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input_1_b;
            string input_2_b;
            string input_3_b;

            decimal input_1;
            decimal input_2;
            decimal input_3;

            input_1_b = Console.ReadLine();
            input_2_b = Console.ReadLine();
            input_3_b = Console.ReadLine();

            input_1 = Convert.ToDecimal(input_1_b);
            input_2 = Convert.ToDecimal(input_2_b);
            input_3 = Convert.ToDecimal(input_3_b);
            decimal output_1 = Math.Max(input_1, input_2);
            decimal output_2 = Math.Max(output_1, input_3);

            Console.WriteLine(output_2);
        }
    }
}
```

I've been using an online compiler while using the exact same program and it saves decimal numbers as normal (ex. 62.5 saves as 62.5)

Here are pictures of the compilers:

[The online compiler (works fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcetK.png)

[Compiler Visual Studio (does not work fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5ogR.png)

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I've already reinstalled Visual Studio but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Locale issue ? Current local setting on your PC doesn't use commas ?

Comment: So it's not a compiler issue but a runtime issue.

Comment: I think I found the problem? When I use , instead of . It works just fine. But am I not supposed to use . (dots)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your PC has a language/culture (locale) setting that uses the dot (`.`) as a digit separator rather than as a decimal point (and, presumably, a comma for the decimal point). That is, 1 million would be written as `1.000.000` and (an approximation to) π would be `3,14159`. In such a culture, the input dots are, effectively, ignored, so `62.3` is read as `623`.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "can't use commas" (otherwise, entering `62,3` and `15,1` for the non-integral input values should work); however, you can fix the issue in two ways:

1. Change the language/region settings of your computer; if you're on Windows 10, it's from "Control Panel" -> "Clock and Region" – and select a language that uses the 'expected' decimal point (like English).
2. You can change the locale programmatically. Create a culture that uses the `dot` for the decimal point (like "en-US") and pass that as a second argument to the `ToDecimal` calls. Here's a modified version of your code that does that:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization; // For the CultureInfo class

namespace OEFGREATEST
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input_1_b;
            string input_2_b;
            string input_3_b;

            decimal input_1;
            decimal input_2;
            decimal input_3;

            input_1_b = Console.ReadLine();
            input_2_b = Console.ReadLine();
            input_3_b = Console.ReadLine();

            // Create an English/US culture and pass that to the ToDecimal calls ...
            CultureInfo CI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
            input_1 = Convert.ToDecimal(input_1_b, CI);
            input_2 = Convert.ToDecimal(input_2_b, CI);
            input_3 = Convert.ToDecimal(input_3_b, CI);
            decimal output_1 = Math.Max(input_1, input_2);
            decimal output_2 = Math.Max(output_1, input_3);

            Console.WriteLine(output_2);

        }
    }
}
```

Note that the above, as it stands, won't change the locale used for any output value; thus, if your largest input is `456.7`, it will be displayed as `456,7` (using the system default locale). You can change this by adding a line like the following, before performing any output (using the same `CultureInfo` object, `CI`):

```cs
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CI; // Use this line to change the UI locale
```

*(To use the above code, you will also need to add a `using System.Threading;` line near the top of your source file.)*

Comment: Thank you Adrian Mole, I followed your instructions and now it works like it should!